# Shortest path with given edges

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, shortest-path

I want to find the shortest path from source(u) using `k` edges. This [solution](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/shortest-path-exactly-k-edges-directed-weighted-graph/) seems to work, but it searches paths with `k` edges to a given node `v`. What if `k` edges are covered before reaching `v`? I just want shortest path from all the paths covered from `u` covering `k` edges. Reaching `v` is not needed.

Code from the above link:

```
# Python3 program to find shortest path 
# with exactly k edges 

# Define number of vertices in the graph 
# and inifinite value 

# A naive recursive function to count 
# walks from u to v with k edges 
def shortestPath(graph, u, v, k): 
    V = 4
    INF = 999999999999
    
    # Base cases 
    if k == 0 and u == v: 
        return 0
    if k == 1 and graph[u][v] != INF: 
        return graph[u][v] 
    if k <= 0: 
        return INF 

# Initialize result 
    res = INF 

# Go to all adjacents of u and recur 
    for i in range(V): 
        if graph[u][i] != INF and u != i and v != i: 
            rec_res = shortestPath(graph, i, v, k - 1) 
            if rec_res != INF: 
                res = min(res, graph[u][i] + rec_res) 
    return res 

# Driver Code 
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    INF = 999999999999
    
    # Let us create the graph shown 
    # in above diagram 
    graph = [[0, 4, 2, 6, 5], 
            [INF, 0, 4, 2, 5], 
            [INF, INF, 0, 4, 3], 
            [INF, INF, INF, 0, 3],
            [INF, INF, INF, INF, 0]] 
    u = 0
    v = 4
    k = 3
    print("Weight of the shortest path is", 
            shortestPath(graph, u, v, k))
```

Comment: I misread that part of your question. I have edited the question to make it easier to read for future readers. However, there are still 3 questions in there: how to make the code do what you want, how does the code work, and if there is any better way to do things. It would be better to ask one question at a time.

Comment: Thanks for editing. Other two questions are removed. Is it ok now?

Comment: Can you explain what output you need? A set of nodes reachable in 3 edges and their shortest distances from the start-node, or the actual paths themselves? This code only returns distance-from-start for `v`, but not a path.

Comment: Not set of nodes. I just want minimum distance to single node which is nearest and which is reached by covering k edges. Only that shortest distance should be the output. The code is returning distance but heading in that link was shortest path, so I wrote that.

Comment: That is not good code to start with, particularly since you didn't write it and don't understand it (and also because it's just bad code). Just use standard [depth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) and limit by edge count.

Comment: @Sneftel - it *is* DFS limited by edge-count, but additionally terminating when `v` is reached

Comment: @tucuxi It's not. It doesn't use a closed set, so it won't have the same performance guarantees as DFS and may result in a path with duplicate edges. It has various other problems as well. I'm not saying that the code is impossible to fix, just that it's not a good starting point.

Comment: @Sneftel ugly DFS is still DFS - even if it will potentially never finish if the graph contains loops. The optimal answer anyway is to use (a modified) Dijkstra - fixing this can only go so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably fix that code (by not passing in, or looking at, `v` at all - see below). But I would recommend simply modifying Dijkstra's algorithm to, at most, explore 3 edges from the start node. Dijkstra finds all shortest-length paths from a start. Simply stop it when paths reach their 3rd edge (this will require you to keep edge-counts in addition to distances).

Modifying the above code also works, but is certainly slower, since you will be looking at each edge multiple times unless the graph is a tree.

```
INF = 999999999999
def nearest_in_k_steps(graph, u, k): 
    print(f"Entering {u}, {k} steps remaining")
    V = len(graph)
   
    # Base case
    if k == 0: 
        return 0, u

    # Initialize result 
    best_dist = INF 
    best_target = None

    # Go to all adjacents of u and recurse 
    for i in range(V): 
        if graph[u][i] != INF and u != i: 
            candidate_dist, candidate_target = nearest_in_k_steps(graph, i, k - 1) 
            candidate_dist += graph[u][i]
            if candidate_dist < best_dist:
                print(f"Hmm, path via {i} (d={candidate_dist}) is better than via {best_target} (d={best_dist})")
                best_dist = candidate_dist
                best_target = candidate_target

    print(f"Returning from {u}, {k} steps remaining: d={best_dist} to {best_target}")
    return best_dist, best_target

# Driver Code 
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    # Let us create the graph shown 
    # in above diagram 
    graph = [[0,    4,   2,   6,   5], 
            [INF,   0,   4,   2,   5], 
            [INF, INF,   0,   4,   3], 
            [INF, INF, INF,   0,   3],
            [INF, INF, INF, INF,   0]] 
    start = 0
    steps = 3
    nearest_dist, nearest_target = nearest_in_k_steps(graph, start, steps)
    print(f"Node {nearest_target} is the nearest {steps}-step neighbor of {start}: distance = {nearest_dist}")
```

Note that there are several prints that are there only to help you understand how the code works.